# Can't give Matrix to Shader as uniform

Tags: opengl, matrix, shader, lwjgl

I'm currently implementing matrices in my enigne. With standard glTranslate and glRotate and then ftransform() in the shader it works. Done manually not.

How i give Matrix to the Shader:

```
public static void loadMatrix(int location, Matrix4f matrix)
{
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    matrix.store(buffer);
    buffer.flip();
    glUniformMatrix4(location, false, buffer);
}
```

Sending viewMatrix:

```
shaderEngine.loadMatrix(glGetUniformLocation(shaderEngine.standard, "viewMatrix"), camera.viewMatrix);
    shaderEngine.loadMatrix(glGetUniformLocation(shaderEngine.obj, "viewMatrix"), camera.viewMatrix);
    System.out.println(camera.viewMatrix.toString());
```

In the shader i get it with:

```
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
```

and in the shaders main i set the frag color:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(viewMatrix[0][3] / -256,0,0,1);
```

Which is BLACK (so viewMatrix[0][3] == 0) while my matrix output in java looks like this:

```
1.0 0.0 0.0 -128.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 -22.75
0.0 0.0 1.0 -128.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion seems to come from how array subscripts address the elements of a matrix in GLSL. The first subscript is the column and the second is the row.

Thus, unless you transpose your matrix, column 1 row 4 == **0.0**.

If you transpose your matrix or swap the subscripts, you will get **-128.0**.

That second parameter in the call to `glUniformMatrix4 (...)` allows you to transpose the matrix before GLSL gets its hands on it, by the way. This will allow you to treat everything as row-major if that is more natural to you.

Comment: So if the first parameter to acces the array is the column, this should be correct: gl_FragColor = vec4(viewMatrix[3][0] / -256,0,0,1);   But it still returns a black color so viewMatrix[3][0] is 0 and viewMatrix[0][0] is 0, too;

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i was giving the matrices to the shader when the used program was 0.